# Swift - Problems receiving images from parse and displaying them

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm having issues fetching the users images from parse and loading them on a table view.. I think it is something to do with the userId /Strings and pointer buissness!

The images upload fine to parse and I can see them, but I cannot seem to download them. My code is definetly the problem, I just can't figure out which part.

On parse the userId is a pointer to the user class, so I'm pretty sure  I've done something wrong connecting it all..! I'm new to swift & Parse so I still have a bit of difficulty understanding it all.

Here's my code below, if anyone understands the problem I would love it if you could tell me!!

```
import UIKit 
import Parse 

class TimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate { 

@IBOutlet var feedTableView: UITableView! 
var refresher:UIRefreshControl! 

var titles = [String]() 
var username = [String]() 
var imageFiles = [PFFile]() 
var users = [String: String]() 



override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad() 

let query = PFUser.query() 
query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in 
if let users = objects { 
self.titles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true) 
self.imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true) 
self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true) 
self.username.removeAll(keepCapacity: true) 
for object in users { 
if let user = object as? PFUser { 
self.users[user.objectId!] = user.username! 

} 
} 
} 



let getFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "followers") 
getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!) 
getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in 
if let objects = objects { 
for object in objects { 
let followedUser = object ["following"] as! String 
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post") 
query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser) 
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in 
if let objects = objects { 
for object in objects { 
self.titles.append(object["title"]! as! String) 
self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"]! as! PFFile) 
self.username.append(self.users[object["userId"] as! String]!) 
self.tableView.reloadData() 


} }}) } } } }) 

// Add the refresher 
refresher = UIRefreshControl() 
refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "") 
refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refreshData", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged) 
// Add the refresher as a sub view on the tableview 
self.feedTableView.addSubview(refresher) 


} 


func refreshData() -> Void { 
self.refresher.endRefreshing()} 

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { 
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. 
} 


@IBAction func blogPost(sender: AnyObject) { 

} 


@IBAction func CameraPopover(sender: AnyObject) { 

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cameraPopover", sender: self) 

} 


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 

if segue.identifier == "cameraPopover" 
{ 
let vc = segue.destinationViewController 
let controller = vc.popoverPresentationController 

if controller != nil 

{ 
controller?.delegate = self 
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 90) 
} 

}} 

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle { 

return.None 
} 

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 
// #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections 
return 1 
} 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
// #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows 
return username.count 
} 


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
let postCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell 

imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in 
if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) { 
postCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage 

} 
} 

postCell.usernameLabel.text = username[indexPath.row] 
postCell.titleLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row] 

return postCell 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you mentioned with the userId pointer is here:

```
let followedUser = object ["following"] as! String 
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post") 
query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser)
```

You mentioned that the `userId` column of the `Post` class is a `User` pointer, however you reference it as a string with `followedUser`.

With regards to the images not displaying properly, they will not be displayed until you refresh the UI. You are using the correct code to load the data which is

```
imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in 
if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) { 
    postCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage 
}
```

However, the issue is that since the data is loaded ***asynchronously***, the `postCell` will be returned to the table before the data has been fetched. The key piece that's missing is to refresh the table using `self.tableView.reloadData()` in the completion handler.

```
imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in 
if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) { 
    postCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Alternatively, I would recommend looking into using a `PFImageView` from the `ParseUI` framework. You assign each of the `PFFiles` to a `PFImageView` in the completion of the query and then call `loadInBackground` on each `PFImageView`. The `PFImageView` class automatically handles updating the images once the data has been loaded.

Comment: Hmm, I added the reloadData. But still nothing, i'm not sure if its connecting to parse, could it be because of the string buissness you mentioned above?

Comment: If the pointer/string stuff is not fixed first it will not work. The `PFFiles` are returned as part of the `Post` query. That query will not return any object as long as there is the invalid constraint of "where a pointer is equal to a string", which will never happen.